# How to hide the UISearchBar in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 tabs: radius search and location search. I am using `UISearchBar` in location search. The two tabs are woking perfectly, but when i search some results in search bar, then immediately click the radius tab, I am attempting to hide the searchbar.

I am using following code :

```
self.searchtextbar.hidden=YES;    
self.searachtextbar=nil;
[self.searchtextbar removeFromSuperView];
```

The above three statements are executing, but it's not working and search bar is not hiding.

please give any ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: In which method you have above code ?

Comment: in radius tab, as well as in viewwillAppear

Comment: use viewwillDisappear in Location.

Comment: i already used these 3 statements in viewWillDisappear, viewdidDisappear and viewDidUnload, but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use

```
self.searachtextbar=nil;
[self.searchtextbar removeFromSuperView];
```

in this order. Once you set `self.searachtextbar=nil;` you can not remove it from superview since you have set the value of `self.searachtextbar` as nil. It is equivalent to `[nil removeFromSuperView];` which will not do anything.

Also make sure that `self.searachtextbar` is not nil before executing `self.searchtextbar.hidden=YES;`